# Vertically positioning pseudo image element (CSS)

Tags: css, image, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

I am using a `:before` pseudo element to add a small image to a download link on my site. The height of the image is greater than the line height and the bottom of the image aligns with the bottom of the text.

How can I alter the vertical alignment of the pseudo element? Ideally so the center of the image aligns with the center of the text?

Comment: Have you tried adding padding to the :before element?

Answer (score 3):

I find that this works in most cases, as long as the text and image aren't way out in scale:

```
#elem:before
{
    content: url(image.png);
    position: relative;
    bottom: -.5ex;
    margin-right: .5em;
}
```

The `margin-right` puts a little bit of space between the image and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Make image `inline` elment, set line hegth to it and set vertical allign to container.

Comment: I solved this (visually at least) by using the image as a no-repeat background to the link instead of a :before element. I had to use `display: block` and set the height of the link to the height of the image, then used `padding-left` and `padding-top` to position the link correctly with respect to the image background.

Comment: I tried making making the pseudo element have a line-height but the element doesn't appear. Are there any other properties that need to exists for the pseudo element to appear properly when it's set to display: inline?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an elegant solution. Here is a jsFiddle with a working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/pAcDE/

Given the following element:

```
<div id='elem'>Bob Cravens</div>
```

I have this CSS:

```
#elem:before{
    content: '';
    height: 160px;
    width: 136px;
    background: url('http://bobcravens.com/Content/images/author_thumb.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#elem{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 60px 136px;
}
```

The :before is probably what you have except for the 'position: absolute' style. Then I used a margin to offset the original div.

Hope this helps.

Bob